# How to get name and value of csrf_token in Python

Tags: python, django

I am adding {% csrf_token %} in my form and when display in browser it

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="PoSJf1brkjNTWeyHhlHHc0FMHlEEa4Wo">
```

How can I get the name and value of this input tag to transfer in data of ajax

Comment: If you're making an AJAX request with CSRF enabled, you should do it the other way, as official docs suggests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 1):

Use this jquery method to get the value of input tag having name as `csrfmiddlewaretoken`

```
var csrf_value = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhvmw4m2/4/)